# Spring Boot 2: set loglevel in custom starter?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-boot-starter

Is it possible to set the loglevel as part of the configuration of a custom starter?

Lets say that I've, for example, created a custom starter that extends the default spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Is it possible to set the loglevel for `org.hibernate` to `WARN` as part of the starter so that every application that uses my custom starter automatically inherits this without having to switch from `INFO` to `WARN` in their own properties file?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend doing this by adding a property source to the environment that contains the `logging.level.org.hibernate` property set to `WARN`.

To do so, you can use `META-INF/spring.factories` to register an implementation of `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.  The `spring.factories` file is a properties file. The keys are the fully qualified class name of the implemented interface. In this case it's `org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor` and the value should be the fully qualified name of your implementation. The contents would like something like this:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.example.HibernateLoggingEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

In your `EnvironmentPostProcessor` implementation you should add a `PropertySource` to the `Environment`. That property source should contain a `logging.level.org.hibernate` property with a value of `WARN`. For example, you could use a `MapPropertySource` created using `Collections.singletonMap`.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much! Whoever is also interested in this, see [this](https://blog.frankel.ch/another-post-processor-for-spring-boot/) and [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceEnvironmentPostProcessor.java) for even more informations about the `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.